# How to implement QML SplitView for three or more elements

Tags: qml, qtquick2, pyqt6, splitview

I'm trying to user PyQt6 to build Desktop app. I need to build a UI presentation with three logical sections which can be resizable by horizontal axis. Looks like SplitView is a perfect component for my goal. Unfortunately I can't make it works as desired.

I found a [simple example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-splitview.html#addItem-method) in official documentation for Qt version 5 that describes exact UI result I'm looking for.
[image]

So I decided to reuse the code under Qt version 6

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts

ApplicationWindow {
    height: 600
    visible: true
    width: 1200

    SplitView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        orientation: Qt.Horizontal

        Rectangle {
            Layout.maximumWidth: 400
            color: "lightblue"
            width: 200

            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: "View 1"
            }
        }
        Rectangle {
            id: centerItem

            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.minimumWidth: 50
            color: "lightgray"

            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: "View 2"
            }
        }
        Rectangle {
            color: "lightgreen"
            width: 200

            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: "View 3"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I get a different result

[image]

Looks like first two sections width are squeezed to 0

Any ideas?

Comment: Use current example: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-controls-splitview.html Change `Layout.` to `SplitView.`

Comment: Hey @eyllanesc,  you are right. It works now with `SplitView.` settings. Thanks! I'll accept your answer in case you create one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `SplitView` effectively, you should get a handle of the `SplitView` attached properties such as `SplitView.preferredWidth`, `SplitView.fillWidth` and `SplitView.fillHeight`. All other sizing such as `width`, `Layout.fillWidth` should be removed, e.g.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    title: "SplitView Demo"
    SplitView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        orientation: Qt.Horizontal
        Rectangle {
            SplitView.preferredWidth: 200
            SplitView.fillHeight: true
            color: "lightblue"
            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: "View 1"
            }
        }
        Rectangle {
            id: centerItem
            SplitView.preferredWidth: 200
            SplitView.fillHeight: true
            color: "lightgray"
            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: "View 2"
            }
        }
        Rectangle {
            SplitView.fillWidth: true
            SplitView.fillHeight: true
            color: "lightgreen"
            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: "View 3"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAADn3icvZDPTsMwDMbveQqrD1CNccsVDuPGBoJzSL3Wwk0qzxX/1HcnHWMsVOMwafgU+/ti+2dquygKS1325J8NZWl5FYNK5I25dTXCh4EUSspoobjrmPSB8AWusY3FVvupfXnHcME3UTblmpgtdE4w6F6MQil1SjHYNLVcpMJ7Gup4b1mhVxdqxoOe2ayyE1yjCFaPVGljYT6bHXGOOyyQ6kYtqPSY2XzkKAmMR/2Jeywy+R5f9dcKh3g+caDchAnid2j6n7pvr3ORtx7M9HUMmyoLu1mK7T9epBb3dr6LzE+/SA6zI56wnIaMGM7HfPk382AG8wmKpfL0)

[EDIT: Oh, I see that @eyllanesc effectively had this answer 7 hours ago]